# Poynting vector exists only in vacuum?

Tags: definition, vacuum, dielectric, poynting-vector

The Poynting vector is defined as $\vec{S}=c^2\epsilon_0 \vec{E}\wedge \vec{B}$ in vacuum. Can we replace $\epsilon_0$ by $\epsilon$ when we consider dielectric ?

Comment: The title of your question does not reflect the body.

Answer (score 1):

The Poynting vector is more generally given by
$$\vec S = \vec E \times \vec H$$

Under the circumstances in which $\vec H = \vec B/\mu$, this becomes $\vec S = \frac{\vec E \times \vec B}{\mu}$.  As the (phase) speed of light in a material is $v=1/\sqrt{\mu \epsilon}= c/n$, this can be written
$$\vec S = \frac{\epsilon c^2}{n^2} \vec E \times \vec B$$

Answer (score 0):

This question is closely related to the 100+ year old  Abraham-Minkowski controversy. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Minkowski_controversy. Some physicists favor the $\vec E \times \vec H$ form, others argue in favor of $\vec D \times \vec B$. Still others reject both.